# NonLinearModelFit not generating a model without the use of "BestFit", not sure why

Tags: fitting

This is my first time using `NonLinearModelFit` and I have run into an issue that I can't find an explanation for. The fitted model contains a `<<19>>` in it but when I look at the estimates for the parameters using `"ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable"` a value has been calculated for the parameter whose place has been taken by `<<19>>`. I found that using `"BestFit"` will give me the proper fitted model but I want to know why `<<19>>` was there in the first place and where it came from. I couldn't find an explanation for this specific issue elsewhere.

Here is a sample of my code and the fitted model generated before using `"BestFit"`

```
data = {{1.0, 1.0, 0.051}, {1.0, 2.0, 0.072}, {2.0, 3.0, 0.16}, {0.5, 
    2.0, 0.033}, {4.0, 5.5, 0.49}, {1.5, 4.0, 0.14}, {6.4, 2.0, 
    0.43}, {6.0, 4.0, 0.62}};
soln = NonlinearModelFit[data, k*cA^n*cB^m , {k, n, m}, {cA, cB}, 
  MaxIterations -> 200]
soln["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable"]

FittedModel[ 0.04106 cA^<<19>> cB^0.607558 ]
```

According to the confidence interval table, the estimate for n (<<19>>) is 1.04206. 
Using `"BestFit"` I get this result for the fitted model:

```
soln["BestFit"]
0.0410613 cA^1.04206 cB^0.607558
```

Why is that? Is there a way to get that solution without using `"BestFit"`?

Comment: Try `Normal@soln`. If I understand correctly your concern is the [`Skeleton`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Skeleton.html?q=Skeleton&lang=en).

Comment: << ...>> is used to print results in shortened form, or to hide some detail considered to be less necessary. The results returned by `NonlinearModelFit` are an example of this. You get a object that can be 'questioned' for various interesting things that it knows of itself. You do this by passing arguments to the object (like "BestFit"). What you see as FittedModel[ 0.04106 cA^<<19>> cB^0.607558 ] is just a visual representation of this object, a tag, or a label and not really meant to be *the answer*. The 19 in the label is an indication of how much data (in the label) has been hidden.

Comment: So, using `soln["BestFit"]` is really the intended way to get your fit, although you also could use `Normal`. You could also attach `["BestFit"]` to the `NonlinearModelFit` function call like this: `NonlinearModelFit[...]["BestFit"]`

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I think that if you are not voting to close as "simple mistake" you should post your comments as an answer :)

Comment: @kuba  I can't, you already closed it ;-)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries oh, indeed, but you had 3 hours to do so :)